# Android loadLibrary path not found

Tags: java, android

I'm using `System.loadLibrary("xxxx");` to load the library but I'm getting the error message again.

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com .xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libchilkat.so"**

**Java code:**

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("chilkat");
       }
```

[My Libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miamb.png)

================================================

**UPDATE**

When you just enter Android Studio, it will create a folder named libs at the path `<Project>\app\libs`

I moved the libs folder to the path `<Project>\app\src\main\`

and extra gradle file

```
android {
  ....
      sourceSets {
      main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
  
          }
     }
```

it worked fine for me